# Problem with generated $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $X$ and $a \in X$, determine the generated $\sigma$ algebra
$\sigma(\{a\})$.

I think it will be $X$, $a$ and $\emptyset$!
What I can prove my answers.

Can you help please.

Comment: You know that a sigma algebra is closed under a certain collection of operations.  What are those operations?  You know your signal algebra contains $\varnothing$, $\{a\}$, and $X$.  What do you get when you apply those operations to individuals and pairs of those three sets?  Anything not on that list?  If you get something new, what happens when you use all the operations on the extended list of sets?  Do you ever run out of new sets by applying the operations?

Comment: $\sigma(\{a\})= \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{ a\}^c , X \}$, where $\{a\}^c= X \setminus \{a\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the set $\mathcal{C} = \{a\}$ of $X$, where $a \in X$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$, $\sigma \mathcal{C}$ will be equal to $\{X, \{a\}, \{a\}^C, \emptyset\}$. So you were quite close; you just needed the complement of $\{a\}$, $\{a\}^C$.

If you didn't have $\{a\}^C$ then $\sigma \mathcal{C}$ would not be closed under complements, which is a necessary condition for a set to be considered a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: If you have any questions, please let me know, I am happy to assist.

Comment: thank you so much! I have other questions but they are about another exercise of these contents, but it will be better to open a new topic so I can help other people in the chat in the future. Thank you one more time.

Comment: No problem @laraazevedo I am also somewhat new to measure theory and am learning about it to be able to tackle theory of probability. Hope you have a nice night / day!

Comment: $a$ is an element of $X$, so $a^C$ does not make sense. I think you mean $\{a\}^C$.

Comment: $\mathcal{C} = \{a\}$  is not a partition of $X$. A partition is a collection of subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{a\}$  is just one subset of $X$.

Comment: I read $a \subset \Omega$ not $a \in \Omega$, I will change it now. Thank you for spotting this.

Comment: In the question $a \in X$,  so  $\{a\}^c \in \sigma(\{a\}) $

Comment: If $A \subset X$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{A\}$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$, $\sigma (\mathcal{C})$ will be equal to $\{X, A, A^C, \emptyset\}$.

Comment: @Ramiro Indeed, I was operating under the notion that $A \subset X$ until you pointed out otherwise. Then I saw that I had misread $A \in X$ as $A \subset X$.

Comment: In your answer now, is  $A \in X$ or $A \subset X$ ?

Comment: Why did you change lowercase $a$ by uppercase $A$?  $A$ looks like a subset of $X$.

Comment: @Ramiro There was no solid reason for the notational change and I agree that it could be misconstrued as a subset of $X$ instead of an element of $x$, despite the previous contexts provided that would imply otherwise. So, I have changed them back.

Comment: OK. The issue was not the lowercase $a$, but the absence of $\{\}$ around the $a$. Now it is solved.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you for your assistance with refining my answer and pointing out to me my misreading of the question. Unrelated, but I tagged you on a question of mine from several days ago that might be interesting; I would be grateful if you could offer me some insights with it.